# Graphical packages not installed by mistake, lubuntu

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

So I installed lubuntu on my new laptop, but when it came to choosing what packages to install, I accidentally didn't install anything including the desktop. Can anyone help me get a GUI and where I can install packages afterwards.

(I only have command prompt if that wasn't clear)

Comment: Why don't you just re-install?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a live disk or USB? Boot from it and reinstall.
If you have access to the web, through the command prompt try

```
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```